# How to best convert coordinates from tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates

I have a simple coordinate system that I want to display on a tkinter canvas. When the user clicks on a cell, I want to print out its location:

[image]

Each cell on the canvas has a height and width of 15, so when the user clicks on a cell, the corresponding event is not the actual x and y coordinate.

What I had in mind is drawing rectangles with the different heights and widths on the canvas:

```
x1 = 0
x2 = 0
y1 = 15 
y2 = 15
for i in range(4):
    for i in range(8):
        canvas.create_rectangle(x1, x2, y1, y2, fill="blue",tags="playbutton", outline="green")
        x1 += 15
        y1 += 15
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 15
    x2 += 15
    y2 += 15

def clicked(*args):
    x = args[0].x
    y = args[0].y
    print(convert_to_coordinates(x,y)


canvas.tag_bind("playbutton","<Button-1>",clicked)
```

The convert function would then look something like this:

```
def convert_to_coord(x,y):
   converted_x = None
   converted_y = None
   if x >= 0 and x <= 15:
       converted_x = "A"
   elif x > 15 and x <= 30:
       converted_x = "B"
   elif x > 30 and x <= 45:
       converted_x = "C"
   elif x > 45 and x <= 60:
       converted_x = "D"
   elif x > 60 and x <= 75:
       converted_x = "E"

   if y >= 0 and y <=15:
       converted_y = "1"
   elif y > 15 and y <= 30:
       converted_y = "2"
   elif y > 30 and y <= 45:
       converted_y = "3"
   elif y > 45 and y <= 60:
       converted_y = "4"

   return "{}{}".format(converted_x, converted_y)
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Looks kinda clunky and lots of hardcoded values to me.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the exact ranges of values for x and y for each cell? That would help a lot

Comment: updated my code, added the full conversion function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of less hardcoded stuff:

```
dx = 15 # this can be an optional argument of the convert function
xcells = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
for jx, xcell in enumerate(xcells):
   if x > jx*dx and x <= (jx+1)*dx:
       converted_x = xcell
       break
if x == 0:
    converted_x = xcells[0]
```

same for ycells of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use div operator //

```
converted_y = y // 15 + 1
converted_x_idx = x // 15
```

And map converted_x_idx to one of the letters ABCDE with a list or str.